# Sqlite WALmode do not support memory mode?

Tags: sqlite, connection, checkpoint, wal

I create my sqlite DB connection by using memory mode:

> connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:file:" + dbName + "?**mode=memory&cache=shared**")

And then use WAL-mode by excute: "**pragma journal_mode=WAL**"

I found that the memory size growing all the time when insert/delete operation. And it can not release even i call the wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE).

Answer (score 3):

A in-memory database only supports [memory mode or no journal](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode). Using a journal file for a database that only exists in RAM and goes away when the program that uses it exits doesn't make any sense.